# What does the extremely fragile glass do in Kindle3's pearl e-ink display?

Tags: kindle, e-ink, hardware, display

I've recently seen two great tutorials that disassemble the Kindle 3 for repairing. One is this great [Fix your broken Kindle Keyboard Screen](http://www.instructables.com/id/Fix-your-broken-Kindle-Keyboard-Screen/?ALLSTEPS) tutorial by ghwhitcher, and the other is the [Amazon Kindle 3 Take-apart Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BhTqbslijc) by Powerbook Medic.

Both warn that on the display's back there is an ***extremely*** **fragile layer of glass**. ghwhitcher says that it is *only kept unbroken for normal operation because the kindle3's case is strong enough to protect it to some degree*. He actually broke it first, even with being careful I suppose, when disassembling—he warns.

My question is, what does this glass do? I mean, why does it screw the *entire* display part if it gets broken? What is this glass' function as part of the screen module?

---

illustration taken from the tutorial:

[image: broken kindle]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

E-ink displays have to be mounted on a surface. In this case I assume that was done on the glass. This keeps the E-ink nice and flat (good for equal visibility of all pixels) and for extra reflectiveness of ambient light, if the glass is part of a mirror (as it seems to be).

The display is actually a [thin film transistor array](http://www.eink.com/modules.html) and my guess is that if the supporting glass breaks, some of the circuitry of the thin film get ripped. A single rip across the width or height would make addressing the film **as an array** impossible.